# Magento 2 Block not adding

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 related Problem:
The header.phtml gets included but the purchase.phtml doesn't and we can't find the issue why. This bug only appears on our success page

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
     <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
      <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_header" as="ec_header" template="header.phtml" />
            <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_purchase" as="ec_purchase" template="purchase.phtml" >
             <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_datalayer" as="ec_datalayer" template="datalayer.phtml" />
             <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_impressions" as="ec_impressions" template="impression.phtml" />
             <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_search" as="ec_search" template="search.phtml" />
             <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_detail" as="ec_detail" template="detail.phtml" />
            </block>
  </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
         <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_noscript" as="ec_noscript" template="noscript.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
         <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_events" as="ec_events" template="events.phtml" />
         <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_promotions" as="ec_promotions" template="promotions.phtml" />
            <block class="Anowave\Ec\Block\Track" name="ec_footer" as="ec_footer" template="footer.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want call templates in a template. Try insert the code below in your purchase.phtml:

```
include ($block->getTemplateFile('Anowave_ec::search.phtml'));
```